# Can we create an API Key for a user from the Super user in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to create API Keys for a restricted user from the Super user in Kibana but i can't figure it out. If its even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elasticsearch security endpoint for that for more information check Elasticsearch official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that link is returning a 404 Error.

Comment: Could you share your ES version?